# Rookie trying php: undefined index

Tags: php

I'm trying to send data using a url from an application to a php script, which in turn inserts the data from the URL parameters into an mysql database. Hereunder is my (basic and fully stripped) code, I'm aware of the fact that I miss things like error handling etc.

```
<?php
$hoppie_test=$_GET['{hoppie_test}'];

$servername= "localhost";
$username= "root";
$password= "";
$db="messageserver";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $db);

$sql = "insert into test(hoppie.test, time)values('$hoppie_test')";

$conn->close();
?>
```

The application I use to send the data, uses urls with parameters to transfer the message/data:

```
<url>http://localhost/acars.php?${hoppie_test}</url>
```

I keep getting the following error:

```
Notice: Undefined index: {hoppie_test} in D:\XAMPP\htdocs\acars.php on line 3
```

I'm kinda going crazy here, having tried a lot of possible options from research. Guess I'm too new to all this but I'm trying to learn as I go along. Any pointers or tips would be more than welcome
Thanks

Comment: You probably want to look for `$_GET['hoppie_test']`. Also, be aware you're wide open to SQL injection attacks by taking data passed in the URL and passing it straight into your SQL queries.

Comment: Are you sure your field is called `{hoppie_test}` and not `hoppie_test`? I don't know how this URL is generate but if it is done through PHP then it's likely treated as variable interpolation so that curly braces are not part of the variable name.

Comment: Also, your SQL seems broken.

Answer (score 1):

Simply put, your 'undefined index' notice will be you attempting to access an array element which doesn't exist.

In this case (without seeing the output of `${hoppie_test}` in your `<url>...</url>` string, I cannot tell you what your array key will be, but in PHP the format will be as the following: `<url>yoururl.com?key=value&key=value...</url>`. You could see this structure by simply running `print_r($_GET)` and finding that your parameter is being passed as you expect it to be.

Although as Dharman points out in the comments, the  approach you are taking is very vulnerable and has bad practices baked into it (since you are letting user input interact with your database directly).